# responsive website vs device specific multiple websites

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need some suggestions/views here.

While creating a website which approach will be best to use - device specific multiple websites or single website with responsive design?
What are the advantages and disadvantages of these two types?
Can anyone update on this or redirect me to some related information?

Thanks,
Trupti

Comment: responsive website is for all (different screen resolutions)

Comment: Hi, please always remember to do a quick Google search first before asking a question. When entering your question title into the search field, I see a number of very useful results on the first page, for example [this article.](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/22/separate-mobile-responsive-website-presidential-smackdown/) Or this: http://connect.icrossing.co.uk/mobile-optimisation-strategy-responsive-design-or-standalone-site_10412

Answer (score 0):

As a quick thought, I see the following 3 aspects:

- Responsive design is for all *screen resolutions* (all in one).
- No need of file maintenance for each device (may a little burden your CSS [[Media Queries]](http://www.broken-links.com/2011/02/21/using-media-queries-in-the-real-world/)).
- Responsive is little pain, when we need to support IE.

Better to be responsive rather than specific.